# Getting error installing custom build tensorflow 1.12 wheel with python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, hdf5, h5py, python-wheel

I am trying to install a custom tensorflow 1.12 wheel on ppc64le
IBM Power9 system with NVIDIA Pascal V100 but getting the following error:

```
gcc -pthread -B /ccs/home/shubhankar/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DH5_USE_16_API -I./h5py -I/tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/lzf -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/ccs/home/shubhankar/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/ccs/home/shubhankar/miniconda3/include/python3.6m -c /tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/h5py/defs.c -o build/temp.linux-ppc64le-3.6/tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/h5py/defs.o
    In file included from /ccs/home/shubhankar/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1821:0,
                     from /ccs/home/shubhankar/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                     from /ccs/home/shubhankar/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/h5py/api_compat.h:26,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/h5py/defs.c:657:
    /ccs/home/shubhankar/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
      ^
    In file included from /tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/h5py/defs.c:657:0:
    /tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/h5py/api_compat.h:27:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
     #include "hdf5.h"
                      ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of h5py
Command "/ccs/home/shubhankar/miniconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-5_3ofwib/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/
```

It breaks at the installation of h5py for some reason. It all starts with a warning message. I am not sure if it is related to it.

```
Cythonizing /tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/h5py/h5z.pyx
    /tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/.eggs/Cython-0.29.1-py3.6-linux-ppc64le.egg/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/h5py/h5z.pxd
```

And finally

```
Rolling back uninstall of h5py
Command "/ccs/home/shubhankar/miniconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-5_3ofwib/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-d__8pdpg/h5py/
```

I am using miniconda3 for package management. The system installed gcc version is 4.8.5

Answer (score 0):

You're installing `tensorflow` on a non-standard architecture (there are no precompiled wheels [at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.12.0/#files)) so `pip` has to compile everything (including dependencies, including `h5py`) from sources.

To compile `h5py` from sources you need to install HDF5 1.8.4 or newer **with development headers**. See http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/build.html#source-installation for details.

Install `libhdf5-dev` using your OS' package manager if the package is available. Or [install HDF5 from sources](http://micro.stanford.edu/wiki/Install_HDF5#Build_and_Installation_from_Sources).

Comment: Doesn't anaconda already take care of hdf5. I tried building from source on a power8 and Nvidia Tesla non-standard architecture but never faced the same issue.

Comment: You didn't mention `anaconda` in the question.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I will update the question accordingly.